# Getting output of linux terminal using java?

Tags: java, linux, stream, terminal, output

Hello here is my code which is letting me to send a code and recieves the result, but what i want to see is a process of a script, this code only shows the last results at that moment nott all the logs. Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
try{

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.connect(10*1000);
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("command".getBytes());
            channel.setInputStream(is);
            channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

            channel.connect(15 * 1000);
            session.connect(10*1000);

            // Disconnect (close connection, clean up system resources)
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
             System.out.println("Exception found while streaming.");
        }
```

Comment: "Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code?"- `catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a long shot, but why don't you use a debugger to debug your code ? Are you develop using a IDE ? If that is the case most of time java debuggers are inbuilt with them. If this is a part of a another code get this part into a main method of a java class and debug it.